# How does this expression vanishes?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, sturm-liouville

I have $Y=Y(y)$ and $$Y''-(n\pi)^2Y=0 \qquad \text{with} \qquad Y(0)=0 \,\,\,\, Y(1)=0$$

My book writes $Y = A_n \sinh{n\pi y} + B_n\cosh{n\pi y}$ and then says that this gives $Y \equiv 0$

> Why does it give the trivial solution?

**My trial**
$$Y''-(n\pi)^2Y=0 $$ gives exponential solution $Y = Ae^{n\pi y}+Be^{-n\pi y}$ using $Y(0)=0$ we have $A=-B$ and therefore $Y= A(e^{n\pi y}-e^{-n\pi y})$ or if you want $Y=2A\sinh{n\pi y}$

Applying the other doesn't give $A=0$ though.. $Y(1)=0$ gives $0 = 2A\sinh{n\pi}$

> Can someone explain to me how we get the trivial solution?

Comment: $A(e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi})=0$ yields either $A=0$ or $n=0$. Does it state that the differential equation must hold for some n unequal to zero? If so, then $A=0$.

Comment: For any $n \neq 0$, you have $\sinh(n\pi) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Meneer-Beer No, I don't think so. It comes from solving $\nabla^2 \phi(x,y)=0$  by separation of variables, on the square $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$ with boundary conditions $\phi(0,y)=\phi(1,y)=\phi(x,0)=\phi(x,1)=0$. After using the Ansatz $ \phi = X(x)Y(y)$, substituting into $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ and dividing through by $\phi = XY$. We obtain two eigenvalue problems $X''-\lambda X=0$ with $X(0)=0$ and $X(1)=0$ and $Y''+\lambda Y=0$ with $Y(0)=0$ and $Y(1)=0$

Comment: From the $X$ eigenvalue problem we get $X_n(x) = \sin{n\pi x}$ (up to a multiplicative constant) with $\lambda_n = -(n\pi)^2$. Substituting into $Y$ eigenvalue problem we have $Y''-(n\pi)^2Y=0$ with $Y(0)=Y(1)=0$. The rest is in the question